# Weird double menu bars

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments, window

I fixed some problem with my Ubuntu install (display sometimes not waking up after sleep) and in the process somehow I managed to bring GNOME into a state where some windows, but not all have these super weird double menu bars. See attached image. Some other programs, like Chromium, look normal having only one menu bar. I really would like to get rid of the redundant menu bars... I do not understand and cannot reconstruct what happened there. How can I fix this please?

[image]

--

Versions used:

Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, GNOME 3.36.8, Windowing System X11

Comment: does this persist when you restart or log out/in? what changes did you make, exactly?

Comment: It does persist after logging in and out, and also restart. As for what changes I did, I am unable to reconstruct what I did. Mostly, re-installing the GNOME libraries.

Comment: I also removed the nvidia drivers because those were apparently what caused the monitor to not wake up from sleep.

Comment: You will need to tell what gnome shell extensions you have installed.

Comment: @vanadium how can I determine which gnome shell extensions I have installed? (I do not think I ever installed any.)

Comment: OK, then the issue will not be a misbehaving custom extension.